# json parsing data store in array in ios 7

Tags: ios, iphone, json, nsarray

this is response which i get from API

```
 {
Result =     {
    Area =         (

        "Shah-e-Alam",
        Vastrapur,
        "Nava Vadaj",
        Ambavadi,
        "Elis Bridge",
        Ranip,
        Gota,

    );
};
Status = Success;
 }
```

now i need store in array only 7 areaname how i store it ?
my code is here

```
      if ([[res valueForKey:@"Status"]isEqualToString:@"Success"]) {
         NSLog(@"%@",res);
         arrAreaname = [[res valueForKey:@"Result"] mutableCopy];

           arrarea=[[arrAreaname valueForKey:@"Area"]mutableCopy];
                 NSLog(@"arrarea: %@", arrarea);

          NSData *json = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arrarea      
             options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", json);

            NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:json 
             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

       NSLog(@"JSON string: %@", jsonString);



   }else{
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR"
        message:@"connection error"
            delegate:nil
            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
        otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [message show];
  }
```

i get here jasonstring in last now how i store data in array ?

Comment: You can add data in dictionary and then add that dictionary in array like      NSArray *Array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[dic objectForKey:@"Result"]];

Comment: Use array like NSArray *Array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[dic objectForKey:@"Result"]valueforKey:@"Area"]

Comment: You've put your cart before your JSON horse.  If the above NSLog output is of `res` then it's already been parsed by NSJSONSerialization and you don't need to do it again.  What you call `arrarea` is your final array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writting dictionary to json data, instead of Reading.

```
// Use following lines to read JSON response.

NSDictionary *dictResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:<json data> options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
NSArray *areas = [NSArray arrayWithArray:dictResult[@"Result"][@"Area"]];
NSLog(@"Areas : %@ %@",dictResult[@"Result"][@"Area"],areas);
```

Comment: JSON string: [
    "Shah-e-Alam",
        "Vastrapur",
        "Nava Vadaj",
        "Ambavadi",
        "Elis Bridge",
        "Ranip",
        "Gota",
]

i need same result in array format

Comment: @UjeshPatel have you tried given snippet? put your JSON response Data and it will give you Array in Log, you can store it where ever you want.

Comment: @UjeshPatel i have modified my answer, now it stores areas in array and logs as well. Happy coding :)

Comment: Result itself it Array dude. display of array would be different here. you can loop through all the areas in array. Output is stored in desired format by OS, you can't modify its representation.

Comment: Then you might be filling your data picker before parsing or your array would not be accessible there. make your array as class instance.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your `arrAreaname` is `NSArray`. Look closely in your data:

```
Result =     {
    Area =         (

        "Shah-e-Alam",
        Vastrapur,
        "Nava Vadaj",
        Ambavadi,
        "Elis Bridge",
        Ranip,
        Gota,

    );
};
```

Value for key **Result** is an `NSDictionary`, and value for key Area is `NSArray`.

**EDIT:**

You should do this:

```
arrarea= [NSArray arrayWithArray: res[@"Result"][@"Area"]];
```

Comment: this is output of NSLog(@"%@",res);

Answer (score 0):

this is the sample logic this will help you

```
NSArray *are=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Shah-e-Alam",
                  @"Vastrapur",
                  @"Nava Vadaj",
                  @"Ambavadi",
                  @"Elis Bridge",
                  @"Ranip",
                  @"Gota", nil];
    NSDictionary *dic2=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:are,@"area", nil];
    NSMutableDictionary *dic1=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:dic2,@"Result", nil];
    NSLog(@"dic1=%@",dic1);

    NSArray *array=[[NSArray alloc]init];

    array= [NSArray arrayWithArray:[NSArray arrayWithArray:[[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[dic1 valueForKey:@"Result"]] valueForKey:@"area"]]];

     NSLog(@"array=%@",array);
```

Comment: dic1={
    Result =     {
        area =         {
            Area =             (
               "Shah-e-Alam",
        Vastrapur,
        "Nava Vadaj",
        Ambavadi,
        "Elis Bridge",
        Ranip,
        Gota,
            );
        };
    };
} 

and after it's stop
array argument is not an NSArray'